# Javascript, удаление содержимого элемента после определенного знака

Tags: javascript

Как на javascript удалить все содержимое элемента после точки, включая ее?

Есть класс, предположим class="abc", его содержимое - это проценты. Мне нужно, чтобы отображалось вместо 34.43535 только 34.

Comment: Подсказка:

    var x = Math.floor( 34.43535); // x = 34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, с использованием jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6c2m/

HTML:

```
<span class="abc">34.43535</span>
<span class="abc">34.43535</span>
<span class="abc">34.43535</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.abc').html(function(index, value) {
    return value.split('.')[0];
});
```

Comment: Отлично, все получилось. Спасибо